# Help with jquery tabs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to know how to link (via a regular href anchor on a different page) to content that is inside a tab that is not the default tab. Can this be done? My code will explain hopefully what I require:

My Code:

### The following is my profile_edit.php page:

The javascript:

```
<script src="Javascript/jquery-1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 $(function () {
 var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
 tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

 $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
   tabContainers.hide();
   tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
   $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
   return false;
 }).filter(':first').click();
 }); 
 $(function () {
    var tabs = [];
    var tabContainers = [];
    $('ul.tabs a').each(function () {
      // note that this only compares the pathname, not the entire url
      // which actually may be required for a more terse solution.
        if (this.pathname == window.location.pathname) {
            tabs.push(this);
            tabContainers.push($(this.hash).get(0));
        }
    });

    // sniff for hash in url, and create filter search 
    var selected = window.location.hash ? '[hash=' + window.location.hash + ']' : ':first'; 

    $(tabs).click(function () {
        // hide all tabs
        $(tabContainers).hide().filter(this.hash).show();

        // set up the selected class
        $(tabs).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        return false;
    }).filter(selected).click();
});
</script>
```

The html and PHP (a portion):

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tabNavigation">
     <li><a href="#account_div">Account</a></li>
     <li><a href="#change_password_div">Password</a></li>
     <li><a href="#favorites_div">Favorites</a></li>
     <li><a href="#avatar_div">Avatar</a></li>
  </ul> 
  <div id="account_div">
     <?php include("personal_info_edit.php"); ?> 
     </div>
     <div id="change_password_div">
     <?php include("change_password.php"); ?> 
     </div>
     <div id="favorites_div">
     <?php include("favorites.php"); ?> 
     </div> 
     <div id="avatar_div">
     <?php include("avatar.php"); ?> 
     </div>
   </div>
```

The following is contained in my change_password_submit.php page:

```
$update_pass= ("Password changed successfully.");
header("location:profile_edit.php?update_pass=$update_pass#change_password_div"); 
exit();
```

By default, whenever profile_edit.php is loaded, the personal_info_edit div is shown and the others are hidden. What do I need to change in the code so that I can reference the 2nd div (ie. change_password div and hide the rest after someone changes their password?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps not the most elegant solution, but it should work.

You can have PHP sniff your url variables for the existence of a particular variable.  I'd probably call this something like 'selectedTabId' or something like that.  Then, if that variable exists, you can have jQuery invoke the `click` action on that tab.  You'll want to use switch/case for this rather than just sending through whatever happens to be in the URL, as people can put nasty things there that you don't want your jQuery to run.  I won't do that in my example below, for expediency's sake.

This is a notional example...

```
<?php
if( array_key_exists('selectedTabId',$_GET) ){
  $selectedTabId = $_GET['selectedTabId'];
  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
  echo "jQuery(document).ready(function(){'#$selectedTabId').click()});";
  echo "</script>";
}
?>
```

Give that a shot and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kyle Humfeld. Im not really sure on which page I should put your code in. I was trying my code from a website http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-tabs/ and I'm just starting to learn javascript. Would my code for the change_password_submit.php page remain the same?

Comment: You'd only have to make a minor alteration, that is to put the id of the tab you want to select in your URL, like this: `header("location:profile_edit.php?update_pass=$update_pass&selectedTabId=3#change_password_div");`

Comment: I'll try implement this and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: I finally got the redirects to work. Problem solved and thanks.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it!  If it was my answer that was correct, can you mark the checkmark next to the top of the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I use this thinger: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html

It does that for you. It also does a whole lot on top. It maybe worth implementing instead of your custom solution?

Here's an example of it in action: http://www.estanciaboerne.com/amenities#TAB2entertainment

(This doesn't actually teach you anything, but it is a solution to your problem, so I'm sorry and you're welcome all in one.)

Comment: I also would like to see someone explain how to do this through pure javascript; explain how that plugin does it.

Comment: I'll try this out if I can fix the above. Thanks for the reply Hoatzin.

Comment: I have looked at the code in your link and there are a lot of similarities. I however did not see how to fix my problem. ie, how to redirect to my page containing the div tabs and remember which one was selected last. I got this code from this site jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-tabs . It explains how it works. Thanks again.